# opendaylight bgp-linkstate not making "loc-rib"

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, bgp

ODL version: Carbon

I'm having a problem with getting BGP-LS into the Network Topology.  As you can see from below REST output, I set up "bgp-example" and homed to an external eBGP linkstate peer.  "effective-rib-in", "adj-rib-in", and "adj-rib-out" all populate - but "loc-rib" does not.  For some reason, it is not inheriting the linkstate afi/safi.

I tried debugs for bgp & karaf but saw nothing out of the ordinary (that I could see) - any help would be much appreciated.

thanks
Erik

*bgp configuration
http://192.168.3.42:8181/restconf/config/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance/global-bgp/protocols/protocol/openconfig-policy-types:BGP/bgp-example

```
{
  "protocol": [
    {
      "name": "bgp-example",
      "identifier": "openconfig-policy-types:BGP",
      "bgp-openconfig-extensions:bgp": {
        "global": {
          "config": {
            "router-id": "192.168.3.42",
            "as": 65000
          }
        },
        "neighbors": {
          "neighbor": [
            {
              "neighbor-address": "192.168.3.41",
              "config": {
                "peer-type": "EXTERNAL",
                "peer-as": 65111
              },
              "afi-safis": {
                "afi-safi": [
                  {
                    "afi-safi-name": "bgp-openconfig-extensions:LINKSTATE"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*loc-rib empty
http://192.168.3.42:8181/restconf/operational/bgp-rib:bgp-rib/rib/bgp-example/loc-rib

```
{
  "loc-rib": {
    "tables": [
      {
        "afi": "bgp-types:ipv4-address-family",
        "safi": "bgp-types:unicast-subsequent-address-family",
        "bgp-inet:ipv4-routes": {}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- as you can see, linkstate is making it into every rib, except loc-rib
  http://192.168.3.42:8181/restconf/operational/bgp-rib:bgp-rib/rib/bgp-example

  ```
  {
    "rib": [
      {
        "id": "bgp-example",
        "peer": [
          {
            "peer-id": "bgp://x.x.x.x",
            "supported-tables": [
              {
                "afi": "bgp-types:ipv4-address-family",
                "safi": "bgp-types:unicast-subsequent-address-family"
              },
              {
                "afi": "bgp-linkstate:linkstate-address-family",
                "safi": "bgp-linkstate:linkstate-subsequent-address-family"
              }
            ],
            "effective-rib-in": {
              "tables": [
                {
                  "afi": "bgp-linkstate:linkstate-address-family",
                  "safi": "bgp-linkstate:linkstate-subsequent-address-family",
                  "bgp-linkstate:linkstate-routes": {
                    "linkstate-route": [
                      {
                        "route-key": "AAMAMAIAAAAAAAAFMgEAABoCAAAEAAD+VwIBAAQAAAAAAgMABgEAFQmQAAEJAAUgCv0YAQ==",
                        "identifier": 1330,
                        "advertising-node-descriptors": {
                          "as-number": 65111,
                          "domain-id": 0,
                          "isis-node": {
                            "iso-system-id": "AQAVCZAA"
                          }
                        },
                        "prefix-descriptors": {
                          "ip-reachability-information": "x.x.x.x/32"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "origin": {
                            "value": "igp"
                          },
                          "ipv4-next-hop": {
                            "global": "x.x.x.x"
                          },
                          "as-path": {
                            "segments": [
                              {
                                "as-sequence": [
                                  65111
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        "protocol-id": "isis-level2"
                      }
  ```

  }
- rest of output truncated for brevity/readability

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured this out.... turns out I had not enabled LINKSTATE afi/safi in the global config for ODL BGP.  I had to DELETE my existing global config, then POST, add neighbors, peers, etc.  Now I have the linkstate DB in the loc-rib, AND it's made it to the network topology - BUT - no idea how to view this topology via DLUX....